# Structuring python packages for straightforward importing

Tags: python, python-3.x, module, package

I have a number of functions that I have written myself over time, over time I have placed each of these functions in their own modules (as I thought this was best practice).

I would like take the next step and organise these modules that I can import in fewer lines of code. However, I'm finding that I need to need to use a lot of lines of 'repeated' code to import the functions I want to have access to.

```
my_functions
-src
--__init__.py
--func1.py
--func2.py
--func3.py
```

I have followed [this talk](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GIF3LaRqgXo) tutorial to build this collection of modules into a package thinking that I could use something like

```
import my_fucntions as mf
```

but I have to import each module

```
import func1 as fu1
import func2 as fu2
...

a = fu1.func1()
```

my question is, what do I have to do to be able to import my functions *as a package*, the same way that I would import something like pandas

```
import my_functions as mf

a = mf.func1(arg)
```

I'm finding it difficult to find either a tutorial or a clear simple example of how to structure this so any guidance at all would be useful. If it's just not doable without building something as complex and pandas or numpy thats ok too, I just said I'd try one last shot at it.

Answer (score 1):

Create a `__init__.py` file in both my_functions directory and src directory.
Now in the my_functions `__init__.py` file. No need to edit `__init__` file inside src.

```py
from src.func1 import func1
from src.func2 import func2

__all__ = [
    'func1',
    'func2'
]
```

Now you can use my_functions like below

```py
import my_functions

my_functions.f1()
```

`__all__` gets called when you try to import `my_functions` and allow you to import things you have mentioned using dot notation.

To call a python script from the root call it using dot notation as below

```bash
python3 -m <some_directory>.<file>
```

Comment: I've done this but I just get a `ModuleNotFoundError` when I try to import, unless I try ìmport src`. Should I have multiple `__init__.py` files?

Comment: Are you running your pythonfile from the root or inside another directory?

Comment: I'm in the top level folder for this project, so in the `my_functions` folder.

Comment: You can add `__init__` in my_functions directory and do the same way. I will update the solution.

Comment: @KevOMalley743 accept the answer to close your issue.

Comment: still no joy, I'll play with the files a little more. But thank you for the help thus far.

Comment: @KevOMalley743 did you check the updated answer?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/249101/discussion-between-kevomalley743-and-msvstl).